# How to get code coverage in play 2.6.x

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, code-coverage

I tried to get code coverage as documented in the documentation:

Modules - Cobertura: https://www.playframework.com/modules/cobertura-2.4/home

But this documentation seems to be heavily out of date. Also all answers on this topic on stackoverflow are not working.

**What is the way to get Java code coverage with play version 2.6.x?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get cobertura to work with play but I'm using IntelliJ as IDE.

IntelliJ provides running unit test with coder coverage.
IntelliJ offers it's own code coverage tool, JaCoCo and Emma.

This seems to work well running the tests as normal unit tests.